# How to run bash on CYGWIN

Tags: bash, cygwin

I have created following file with name test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

name = "Elvin John Paul"
echo $name
echo ${name#* }
echo ${name##* }
echo ${name% *}
echo ${name%% *}
```

and I am getting some error as below.
[image]

can anyone tell me what wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things wrong:

- You cannot use spaces around the assignment operator. As your script currently is, bash interprets the line to mean "run `name` with the arguments `=` and `Elvin John Paul`". The line should look like the following:

```
name="Elvin John Paul"
```

- You have Windows-style line endings (CRLF instead of just LF), which results in the error about `$'\r'`. In recent Cygwin versions, you can use `set -o igncr` to ignore carriage returns as part of a CR LF, or you can fix this with `sed` like so:

```
sed 's/\r$//' file > file2
```

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the space on either side of the `=` symbol. Unlike many other programming languages, that space around the assignment operator matters in Bash and other shell scripts.

The correct code should be:

```
name="Elvin John Paul"
```